# Flyway for Bigquery can query project be different than job run project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, flyway, slots

We are using Flyway for Google bigquery to run SQL migrations. Bigquery slots are not allocated to the project where the data resides. We want to run the flyway job from a different project and run flyway scripts for the project where the data resides. Bigquery allows this, however, is this possible with Flyway?